# animate pan gesture

Tags: cocoa-touch, calayer, quartz-graphics, cabasicanimation

i have wrote a subclass of UIView, which in `drawRect:` draws itself. it is actually something like day-long timeline for movie - it draws time axis with ticks and time text labels. it can be zoomed in up to seconds and zoomed out up to all 24 hours. when its zoomed in, it could be scrolled with pan gesture. so here is the question: how can i implement simple animation, when the finger is lifted, timeline continues to scroll for a while and then stops (with negative acceleration)?

two ideas comes to my mind:

1. implement animation by myself using another thread
2. make new class - a subclass of `CALayer` and then use `CABasicAnimation`. add this class to the layers of my view. but here i should totally move all my code written for view to new subclass of `CALayer`, what i dont want to do. would it be ok?

any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to integrate the view in a UIScrollView, let that handle the scrolling and zooming and let your class just do the drawing?

Comment: do you mean creating subclass of `UIScrollView` ?

Comment: no, putting your custom view inside a scrollview, just implementing your drawRect method to redraw itself, but have scrolling and zooming done by the scrollview. It will be a lot easer if you just need to handle the drawing and not all the rest.

Comment: but my view have to respond for zooming and scrolling as well in order to redraw itself properly, because its visual representation depends on zoom level. anyway, i've solved my problem, choosing variant 1 - implementing by myself. thanks for replies!